# Post a text which will be handled by MathJax

Tags: html, mathjax

I have a problem posting text in a html form.
The text (from a textarea) to be posted to a new page to show
 may have the following properties:

1. including latex code to be handled by MathJax between two dollar sign
2. needs to preserve the line break
3. may including html code such as a input tag

I have tried the following methods:

- replace "\r\n" sub-strings to html "br" tag and then post the text to innerHTML of a div or span
  to keep line breaks. But then I need remove the html part in the text beforehand, otherwise,
  if the text include a "input" tag, I will then have a input box in the resulted page!

  What's more, if I remove html tags, then I will accidently remove the sub string like
  a < b, b > c, (if '<' and 'b', 'b' and '>' are adjacent, seems StackOverFlow can't deal with it, too!)
- using a pre tag to keep line breaks, then MathJax doesn't work!

So, can anyone save me for this problem? Thanks in advance! By the way, I use ruby on rails on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could allow MathJax to process `<pre>` tags by removing them from the `skipTags` array in the `text2jax` block of your configuration.  See the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! But again I will face the problem that the text may contains a input tag(or any other HTML tag), then how can I display the tag as plaintext other than a input box?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand what you were after.  For those not using Ruby, you could do `text.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;")` to escape the contents of the string stored in the variable `text`.

Comment: Your method certainly also does this job!

Answer (score 0):

At last, I use skipTags as Mr Cervone mentioned above and put the text into the pre tag. To convert(and preserve) the HTML tag into plaintext format, I use a method provided by ruby called CGI.escapeHTML.